# Positioning Images in HTML (Using a button creating images)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using this code:

```
<div class="divClassName">
<button onClick="functionName1();");'>Enter Text Here</button>
<script>
    function functionName1() {
        var src = "name.jpg";
        show_image("name.jpg", 200, 200, "absolute", 1, "<alt>");
    }


    function show_image(src, width, height, position, zIndex, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height
        img.position = position;
        img.style.zIndex = zIndex;
        img.alt = alt;

        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
</div>
<!-- Use actual names for divClassName, functionName1, and name.jpg if you want to. -->
```

This makes images appear upon button click, but it appears in the top left corner of the screen instead of where I want it to be. I've been trying

```
function show_image(src, width, height, position, left, top, zIndex, alt) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = src;
      img.width = width;
      img.height = height
      img.position = position;
      img.left = left;
      img.top = top;
      img.style.zIndex = zIndex;
      img.alt = alt;
```

...But it doesn't work. Any fixes/answers?

EDIT: Question answered. Used:

```
img.style.position = position;
img.style.left = left;
img.style.top = top;
```

Comment: how did you call the function? I mean the concrete values of the passed arguments.

Comment: Try `img.style.left = left;` and `img.style.top = top;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3yQMZ/

Comment: left+'px' might work though, let me try

Comment: k, I realized I didn't use'img.style.position'. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated :***

If you assign `position:absolute` ,then you must have to give their `left` , `top` or `bottom` , `right` !

So :

you have to pass extra parameter to your function,  where you want to show your `img`:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, position,left,top, zIndex, alt) {  //left,top as example
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.style.width = width;
    img.style.height = height
    img.style.position = position;
    img.style.left = left+'px';
    img.style.top = top+'px';
    img.style.zIndex = zIndex;
    img.alt = alt;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Or Another Short way to give Style to `img` is :

```
img.attributes = "style = left:"+left+"px;top:"+top+"px;...And So on..";
```

Comment: Tried it already, but it didn't work for some reason... I'll try it again

Comment: please go through with my updated Answer, it works!
you have to include `img.style.property` then only this works !

Answer (score 1):

You are positioning the image absolute. So if top = 0 and left = 0 it will render in the top left of the screen.

If you want it to render in the top left of the div. You can still position your image absolute with top = 0 and left = 0.

But: you need to give the parent element a position relative.

so for example:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        // img src etc...
    </div>
<body>
```

and the css should be

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```