# Making a img appear/disappear in html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I've used a button at this link:
[Positioning Images in HTML (Using a button creating images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076168/positioning-images-in-html-using-a-button-creating-images)
...But I want to know how to make the image disappear if it's already been placed by using a button. Hopefully this can use the same button. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please update your question to show the relevant code (HTML, CSS and JavaScript)? Ideally *also* provide a link to a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your code in operation.

Comment: Working w/ JS fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the image and `id="myImage"`

and then

```
if(myImage.style["visibility"]=="visible"){
myImage.style["visibility"]="hidden";
else
{
myImage.style["visibility"]="visible";
}
```

Comment: Wait, I'm making the image appear after you open the web page, so how do I attach the id to the image? Should I add another section into the function? Thanks for the answer, btw

Comment: I found that I could just use the location.reload() function to reload the website. (This wouldn't selectively remove images I placed though, and they would have to be originally not there/hidden)

Comment: Reloading the website is not effective.  You wrote that you placed the image by clicking a button,  so in that function that places the image make it give the image an id or class and use those

Comment: It works for me... Whatever, I'll try. Should I img.id in the function I use to place the image?

Comment: Well if reloading works for you then cool, but it will make you whole page blink and involves more data, if u dont mind then ok.  And yea, the function where you create the image set an id for it and u can simply use that id to remove it.

Comment: The button only worked once though, the rest of the times it wouldn't remove any more of the pictures unless I reload it.

Comment: Make sure the images have uniqye id each. If you want to let ur images have something in common, assign a class to them

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the image by setting its 'display' attribute to 'none'(hidden) or 'initial'(visible). Let your button trigger a function that swaps the state of the image, as follows (Javascript):

```
var img = document.getElementById('yourImageID');

function toggleImg(){
if ( img.style.display == 'none' ){ img.style.display = 'initial'; }
else { img.style.display = 'none'; }
}
```

The attribute 'visibility' will keep the space of the image free and just blank it, where 'display' will not keep the space.